# GradientBoostingRegressor http://scikit-learn.org/ give the same Prediction Intervals for up and lower limits

Tags: python

I try to get Prediction Intervals for GradientBoostingRegresso
per 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_gradient_boosting_quantile.html#example-ensemble-plot-gradient-boosting-quantile-py

```
#  GradientBoostingRegrKessor
# up
alpha_GBR_up = 0.95        
#model_GBR_up = GradientBoostingRegressor(loss='quantile', alpha=alpha, n_estimators = n_trees_simple_RF, learning_rate=0.1,  max_depth=1, random_state= rnd_seed)
model_GBR_up = GradientBoostingRegressor(loss='quantile', alpha=alpha_GBR_up, n_estimators = n_trees_simple_RF, learning_rate=0.1,   random_state= rnd_seed)        
model_GBR_up.fit(past_matrix_RF[:-n_games_test],  true_pts_for_RF[:-n_games_test])      
predicted_pts_simple_GBR_upper  = model_GBR_up.predict(past_matrix_RF)
#down
alpha_GBR_lower =1.0 - alpha_GBR_up
#model_GBR_lower = GradientBoostingRegressor(loss='quantile', alpha=alpha, n_estimators = n_trees_simple_RF, learning_rate=0.1,  max_depth=1, random_state= rnd_seed)
model_GBR_lower = GradientBoostingRegressor(loss='quantile', alpha=alpha_GBR_lower, n_estimators = n_trees_simple_RF, learning_rate=0.1,  random_state= rnd_seed)
model_GBR_lower.fit(past_matrix_RF[:-n_games_test],  true_pts_for_RF[:-n_games_test])
predicted_pts_simple_GBR_lower  = model_GBR_up.predict(past_matrix_RF)

# middle
#model_GBR = GradientBoostingRegressor(loss='ls', n_estimators = n_trees_simple_RF, learning_rate=0.1,  max_depth=1, random_state= rnd_seed)
model_GBR = GradientBoostingRegressor(loss='ls', n_estimators = n_trees_simple_RF, learning_rate=0.1,  random_state= rnd_seed)
model_GBR.fit(past_matrix_RF[:-n_games_test],  true_pts_for_RF[:-n_games_test])
predicted_pts_simple_GBR  = model_GBR.predict(past_matrix_RF)

#    plot
fig = plt.figure(15110606)
plt.plot(predicted_pts_simple_GBR_upper,'go',label = ' predicted_pts_simple_GBR_upper')
plt.plot(predicted_pts_simple_GBR_lower,'cp',label = ' predicted_pts_simple_GBR_lower'   ) 
plt.plot(predicted_pts_simple_GBR,'rd',label = ' predicted_pts_simple_GBR' )        
plt.title("  player  " +  df_player['Name'][1] + '  team ' + df_player['Team'][1] )
plt.xlabel ("Game Number  (not actual , but only order) number of games for test = " + str(n_games_test))
plt.ylabel("PTS") 
plt.plot(predicted_pts_simple_GBR_upper,'g')

plt.plot(predicted_pts_simple_GBR,'r')

plt.plot(predicted_pts_simple_GBR_lower,'--c')
fig.show()
pp.savefig()
```

but I get the same Prediction Intervals for up and lower limits
you may tell that I changed some parameters in example but even changed example works

```
clf = GradientBoostingRegressor(loss='quantile', alpha=alpha,n_estimators=250, learning_rate=.1)
```

and seems to be it is only way to get intervals with ensemble learning, since random forest does not have it

Comment: I changed code to use .set_params(alpha=1.0 - alpha) and .set_params(loss='ls') as in example. And now lower bound is the same as predicted for set_params(loss='ls')